# How to get value from nested <span> tags by .find method in beautifulsoup

Tags: django, beautifulsoup, python-3.7

I am trying to get an information stored in nested  tag by beautifulsoup in my new python project of CRAIGLIST CLONE app using dJango framework.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from django.shortcuts import render
from requests.compat import quote_plus
from . import models

BASE_CRAIGLIST_URL = 'https://ahmedabad.craigslist.org/search/?query={}'
search = request.POST.get('search')
    models.Search.objects.create(search=search)
    final_url = BASE_CRAIGLIST_URL.format(quote_plus(search))
    print(final_url)
    response = requests.get(final_url)
    data = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, features='html.parser')

    post_listings = soup.find_all('p', {'class': 'result-info'})

    final_postings = []

    for post in post_listings:
        post_title = post.find(class_='result-title').text
        post_url = post.find('a').get('href')
        post_price = post.find('span', class_='result-price')

        final_postings.append((post_title, post_url, post_price))

    stuff_for_front_end = {
        'search' : search,
        'final_postings': final_postings,
    }
    return render(request, template_name='myapp/new_search.html', context=stuff_for_front_end)
```

[This is the source from where i want to get the information aboutpricing and all.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOKcZ.png)
I tried this code and i got "None" in output.[See the 3rd line below the submit button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVDO1.png)

Comment: Where the field is none, what are you expecting to see? Looking at the website there doesn't appear to be a price. Also I would recommend adding the bare minium to re-create the issue. For example replacing models.Search.objects.create(search=search) with a hard code url.

Comment: Thank you, I expect that price from the result will shown at the "None",  Which you can see at this URL https://ahmedabad.craigslist.org/reb/d/sw-florida-golf-resort-brand-new-2-bed/7149950472.html

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something. If I view source on https://ahmedabad.craigslist.org/reb/d/sw-florida-golf-resort-brand-new-2-bed/7149950472.html it's missing a class with result-title and result-price. Also it's not the URL you used for scraping in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for collaborating, after some research and i notice that price isn't in 'p' of class = 'result-info' it's 'li' with class = 'result-row' and also that not every post has price.
So i tried some tricks and one of them worked. let's have a look at it.

```
def new_search(request):
    search = request.POST.get('search')
    models.Search.objects.create(search=search)
    final_url = BASE_CRAIGLIST_URL.format(quote_plus(search))
    print(final_url)
    response = requests.get(final_url)
    data = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, features='html.parser')

    post_listings = soup.find_all('li', {'class': 'result-row'})

    final_postings = []

    for post in post_listings:
        post_title = post.find(class_='result-title').text
        post_url = post.find('a').get('href')

        if post.find('span', class_='result-price'):
            post_price = post.find('span', class_='result-price').text
        else:
            post_price = 'N/A'
```

[also I've changed the interface.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAcBL.jpg)